# Android Studio bitmap allocation out-of-memory error

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm using this function to rotate a bitmap from the camera or the gallery:

```
public static Bitmap fixOrientation(Bitmap mBitmap) {

    if (mBitmap.getWidth() > mBitmap.getHeight()) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap , 0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true); // the error is here!
    }
    return mBitmap;
}
```

Its workes fine in the first two times i'm using it, but in the third time it crashes the app and giving me this error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 36578316 byte allocation with 16771872 free bytes and 29MB until OOM
```

This is where this function is called:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {

            Bitmap sourceBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

            Bitmap correctBitmap = fixOrientation(sourceBitmap);
            image.setImageBitmap(correctBitmap);

            bitmapsArray[cameraSideInt] = correctBitmap;
            chooseImageLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // show change layout

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone Think of a way to solve this error?

Comment: Try not storing so many bitmaps in memory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah-  don't save that many bitmaps.  You're storing them in an array.  Bitmaps take lots of memory.  While they're in that array they can't be garbage collected, so that memory is lost.  You probably shouldn't be doing this.

You can look for other memory leaks in your app, they probably exist and may save enough memory to make this doable.  But its a bad idea, especially if the bitmaps are large (anything close to full screen).

Comment: Ok, so how do i save the bitmaps? I get the images from the user (camera or gallery), and i'm moving between several activities, so i need a way to store the images i get.

Comment: Between activities?  Store them to disk and pass the filenames around.